# Jquery UI Autocomplete Custom Value Insert if no records found

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the Jquery UI Code Autocomplete freature. What I want to do is when no records are found I have an option to enter the value to the database by hitting carriage return key ...

Is it possible to achieve it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Logic:-

```
 if (!ui.content.length) {
     $("#btn").show();
     var getNewValue = $("#TextBox_ID").val();
     // Code to Insert this new value
}
```